# Kibana as Elasticsearch monitoring solution

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

Objective is to create a Dashboard in Kibana that include visualizations based on some special queries to monitor Elasticsearch health and status, like `GET /_cluster/settings?include_defaults=true&filter_path=defaults`. the problem is this query is based on no index. how can i go thru it?

Comment: You could make that query at regular interval (e.g. using Logstash) and store the results in an index that you can then query and visualize through an index-pattern.

Comment: @Val that task is reserved for the administrators team, i am not allowed to do that as a simple user.

Comment: Are you able to use X-Pack? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/es-monitoring.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the free version of xpack , cluster monitoring is free.

I am using that already.